# Infinite game of an unfair coin toss

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, infinite-games

Following game between person **A** and **B** is proposed:

> Person **A** has an unfair coin with probability $p \in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})$ of heads. Person **B** starts with a captial of 100€. For each time **B** tosses heads, his captial doubles and is halved if **B** tosses tails. Each time **A** gives or gets the money.

So let $X_n :=$ **B**'s capital after the n'th toss

> Now **A** further says, that $\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n]=\infty,$

Which is to be **proven** or **disproven**.

**My Attempt**: To check this we define $X_0:=100$ and get the recursion:
$$X_n=X_{n-1}(1+W_n),  W_n:= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{B tosses heads}\\
-\frac{1}{2} & \, \textrm{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

If we now write out $X_n$, we get $X_n=100 \displaystyle{\prod_\limits{i=1}^n}(1+W_i)$. Now if we define $Q_i:=(1+W_i)$ and note that $Q_1, \dots , Q_n$ are independent random variables, we get  that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[100 \displaystyle{\prod_\limits{i=1}^n}Q_i]=100 \displaystyle{\prod_\limits{i=1}^n}\mathbb{E}[Q_i]=100 \displaystyle{\prod_\limits{i=1}^n}(2p+\frac{1}{2}(1-p))=100(\frac{3}{2}p+\frac{1}{2})^n \longrightarrow \infty$$

**Question**: I think I have done something wrong because, when calculating $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ without the recursion, so saying

$X_n \sim Bin(n,p,k)$:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\sum_\limits{k=1}^n k P(X_n=k)=\sum_\limits{k=1}^n100(2)^k(\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=100((\frac{3p+1}{2})^n(\frac{1-p}{2})^n) \longrightarrow \infty $$

Which clearly is not the same expected value I got, with the recursion. I would be very grateful, if anyone could point out my mistake. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
As pointed out in the comments of the answer I did not sum over $k=0$, so the correct sum would be:
$$\sum_\limits{k=0}^n k P(X_n=k)=\sum_\limits{k=0}^n100(2)^k(\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=100(\frac{3}{2}p+\frac{1}{2})^n$$
which also delivers the same expected value, as in my attempt and the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did nothing wrong, you can do it with the conditional expectation as well.
We have  $$E(X_{n+1} | X_n) = p 2 X_n + (1-p) \frac{X_n}{2} = (3/2p - 1/2) X_n$$
so
$$E(X_{n+1}) = E(E(X_{n+1} | X_n)) = (3/2p - 1/2) E(X_n)$$
which gives by recurrence
$$E(X_n) = 100 (3/2p - 1/2)^n$$.

Also, I helped someone earlier on the same problem on how to prove the almost sure convergence to $0$ of $X_n$ : (The link was deleted, the explanation is in the comments)

Comment: but why, is there another expected value on the second calculation, e.g. $n=1$ we get $100(2p)\neq 100(\frac{3p-1}{2})$?

Comment: You excluded $k=0$ for no reason :)

Comment: Also, it is not $X_n$ that has a binomial distribution but an auxiliary random variable on which $X_n$ builds on, but I see what you want to write.

Comment: this explains alot, wow

Comment: is there any way possible, you could maybe explain, how you solved the second part in the linked question?

Comment: Ah snap, the page got deleted... First, you rewrite $X_n$ as $2^{Z_n}$ where $Z_n$ is a biased random walk on $Z$. Intuitively, $Z_n$ will roughly tend to $-\infty$ at the rate of a linear function of $n$. Using Hoeffding, you show that $P(Z_n \geq - C_1 n) \leq C_2 e^{-C_3 n}$ where $C_1, C_2$ and $C_3$ are some well chosen positive constants (for instance $-C_1 n = E(Z_n)/2$ and the other two come from Hoeffding). Then, Borel Cantelli tells you that a.s. $Z_n$ tends to $-\infty$ which tells you that a.s. $X_n$ tends to $0$.

Comment: It is possible that simpler concentration inequalities than Hoeffding's will work as well (I did not try), but since $Z_n$ is a sum of bounded random variables, I tried it directly.

Comment: Thats what I didn‘t understand, how does BC tell us that $Z_n \rightarrow - \infty$ a.s. I only know BC in the form, that random variables tend to $0$ or $1$, depending how the series of their respective probabilty con/diveregece. Is there some to trick to get the result you got?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma If you apply this with $E_n = (Z_n \geq -C_1 n)$ then $P(\limsup E_n) = 0$ (because $\sum e^{-C_3 n}$ is finite). In other words, a.s., there are only a finite number of $n$'s such that $Z_n \geq -C_1 n$.