# Convergence of a capital describing random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

In my previous question [Infinite game of an unfair coin toss](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839416/infinite-game-of-an-unfair-coin-toss), I showed that in a game between Person **A** and **B**, where:

> Person **A** has an unfair coin with probability $p \in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})$ of heads. Person **B** starts with a captial of 100€. For each time **B** tosses heads, his captial doubles and is halved if **B** tosses tails. Each time **A** gives or gets the money.

So let $X_n :=$ **B**'s capital after the n'th toss. That $\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n]=\infty$. Now the follow up to this is, to show that:
$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n=0 \})=1$$

To show the first statement I used, that:
$$X_n=X_{n-1}(1+W_n),  W_n:= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{B tosses heads}\\
-\frac{1}{2} & \, \textrm{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

For this statement, we were given the hint:

> Apply the strong law of large numbers, which will be formulated in the following, to $Z_i:=\log(1+W_i), i\in \mathbb{N}$.
> Let $(Z_i)i \in \mathbb{N}$  be a sequence of pairwise uncorrelated random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ with existing expected values and finite variances $\sup_\limits{i∈N} V(Z_i) < \infty$. Then:$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i])=0\})=1.$$

**My attempt**: First of all, I tried to show the requirements, to use the result:
$$P(Z_i=k,Z_j=l)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
p(1-p) =  P(Z_i=\log(2))P(Z_j=-\log(2))\\
p^2 = \ P(Z_i=\log(2))P(Z_j=\log(2)) \\
(1-p)^2=P(Z_i=-\log(2))P(Z_j=-\log(2))\\
\end{array}
\right.,\quad k,l \in \{\log(2),-\log(2)\}$$
So $(Z_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are pairwise independent, thus pairwise uncorrelated.

Then, $\mathbb{E}[Z]:=\mathbb{E}[Z_i]=p\log(2)-(1-p)\log(2)$, so the expected value exists.

$$\sup_\limits{i∈N} V(Z_i)=\sup_\limits{i∈N} \sum_{z \in Z_i(\Omega)}(z-\mathbb{E}[Z_i])^2P(Z_i=z)=\sup_\limits{i∈N} \sum_{z \in \{\log(2),-\log(2)\}}(z-\mathbb{E}[Z_i])^2P(Z_i=z)=\\ \sup_\limits{i∈N}\quad (\log(2)-(2p-1)\log(2))^2+(-\log(2)-(2p-1)\log(2))^2(1-p) < \infty$$

So now that I can use the statement, from the hint, I thought it may be a good idea to rewrite so it:

$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i])=0\})=P(\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i=\mathbb{E}[Z]\})=1.$$

**Question**:But, I don't really see, how this could help me, to show the inital statement. I think I could somehow use $\log(1+x)<x$, due to the definition of $Z_i$. But other than that, I am really stuck on this problem. I would be glad to get some further hints, or maybe an idea how to use the provided hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions of $X_n,W_n$ and $Z_n$ imply
$$
\begin{align}
X_n&=X_0\cdot (1+W_1)\cdot (1+W_2)\cdots (1+W_n)
\\&= X_0\cdot e^{Z_1+\dots+Z_n}.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log(X_n/X_0)=Z_1+\dots+Z_n.
$$
Let $\mu=\mathbb E[Z_1]$, and recall that $\mu<0$. We can rewrite the above as
$$
\frac1n\log(X_n/X_0)=\mu + \color{gray}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (Z_i-\mu)}.
$$
Now, using the Strong Law of Large Numbers, the gray term approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$, with probability $1$. This means that, for all $\epsilon>0$, we have
$$
\frac1n\log(X_n/X_0)<\mu + \epsilon\qquad \text{when $n$ large enough, with probability 1}
$$
By choosing $\epsilon$ small enough, we can ensure $\mu+\epsilon$ is negative. This means that
$$
X_n\le X_0\cdot (e^{\mu+\epsilon})^n\qquad\text{when $n$ is large enough, with probability 1}
$$
Since $\lim_n (e^{\mu+\epsilon})^n=0$, this implies that $\lim_n X_n=0$ with probability $1$.